# Redeployable conda environments

Tags: python, conda

I want to create a conda environment on my laptop that I can deploy to my cluster.  For this I want two things:

1. To be able to create a conda environment for a different architecture
2. To be able to zip up the environment, move it to some other place in some other file system, unzip it, and run `/path/to/myenv/bin/python ...`

I hope that there is some option in conda-create to specify an architecture like the following:

```
conda create --arch=linux-64 ...
```

For redeployability I have tried using the `--copy` option to avoid hard-links and this *seems* to work fine, at least in simple cases.  Are there cases or common packages where this approach will fail?  Are there other things I can do either to increase effectiveness or warn when a package depends on files outside of the environment?

Answer (score 2):

At present, conda does not have a direct way to create environments for arbitrary architectures.  I'm also not sure exactly how feasible it is.  For the vast majority of packages, it's just a metadata thing, and is totally workable.  For binary packages, though, we (sometimes) have to replace the prefix that is embedded in the binary.  Since it is done in Python (https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/9c1750349b4c1d66a9caf95d21a9edf90e1eb9cf/conda/install.py#L250-L271), I think it will work - but if there's any chance of binaries not being understood (Mac creating a Linux env, for example), this may break.

We can certainly hack up a PoC and see how it works.

Packages really shouldn't depend on outside files, aside from perhaps some really core system libraries (glibc, for example).  Warning people at build time would be a good thing, but I don't think it is an install-time concern.

Edit: please see https://github.com/conda/conda-prefix-replacement